# Associate specific string to a number in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am using a google forms to collect responses which I will then use to score people. Unfortunately some of those responses only make sense in a non numeric form, here is an example:

Q: What is your most common mode of transportation?

- Car
- Carpool
- Public transportation
- Bike
- Walk

I want to be able to have google sheets automatically convert those string responses into a number, as in Car will be 20, carpool 15 and so on so that I can "grade" them and give them a score. Can this be done through google forms? Or maybe some sort of dictionary function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method, requiring no coding, would be to make a worksheet with the encoding of the options and then use VLOOKUP to translate them.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! Would you happen to have example code for this?

Comment: It's hard to provide example code without an example spreadsheet, but in  general: First make another sheet with the dictionary, let's say Sheet2, with your options (Car, Carpool, Public transportation, Bike, Walk) in column A, and their values (15, 20, etc.) in column B. Then use  =VLOOKUP(<option>, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE) to translate the options into their values.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this can be done through Google Forms. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/duration-item#setPoints(Integer)

Using their code, you could go something like

```
var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
// Go through each form response
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var response = formResponses[i];
  var items = FormApp.getActiveForm().getItems();
  // Assume it's the first item
  var item = items[0];
  var itemResponse = response.getGradableResponseForItem(item);
  if (itemResponse != null && itemResponse.getResponse() == 'Car') {
   var points = item.asMultipleChoiceItem().getPoints();
   itemResponse.setScore(points * 20);
   // This saves the grade, but does not submit to Forms yet.
   response.withItemGrade(itemResponse);
   }
}
// Grades are actually submitted to Forms here.
FormApp.getActiveForm().submitGrades(formResponses);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick reply! Ill have to try this out after this weekend but this seems to be what im looking for